# how do i put a second string array in for a second text view in a list view

Tags: arrays, listview

Recently I followed a tutorial by derek banas on youtube about how to make a custom adapter and list view.
Link to the video: [Derek Banas List View Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhj4_KBD6BQ&list=UUwRXb5dUK4cvsHbx-rGzSgw)

After watching the video I see the derek has only inserted one string array for one text views for the rows. I have a second string array and a second text view for the rows. I have entered the first array in but how do i enter the string array in so I have two text views for each row.

Here is my adapter.

```
class HangarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


public HangarAdapter(Context context,String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.hangar_layout, values);


}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.hangar_layout, parent, false);

    TextView TextView1 = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView TextView2 = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    TextView1.setText(getItem(position));

    ImageView theImageView = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    return theView;
    }
```

Edit:

```
ListView hangarList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hangarList);

    ListAdapter adapter = new HangarAdapter(this, ship);

    hangarList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: pass the second array in constructor of HangarAdapter say secArray,then set this array TextView2.setText(secArray[position])); OR declare secArray in HangerAdapter itself and access in the same way. If you post the whole Adapter class then I can edit your class to resolve your problem.

Comment: that is the whole adapter class

Comment: ok then please post the class from where you are calling HangarAdapter. or atleast block of code where you are using this adapter class.

Comment: I have edited the main question and added the code from HangarActivity where i create the list view and set its adapter to HangarAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class HangarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String []ship1;
String []ship2;

public HangarAdapter(Context context,String[] values1,String[] values2) {
    super(context, R.layout.hangar_layout, values);
ship1 = values1;
ship2=values2;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.hangar_layout, parent, false);

    TextView TextView1 = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView TextView2 = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    TextView1.setText(ship1[position]);
    TextView2.setText(ship2[position]);

    ImageView theImageView = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    return theView;
    }
```

Now in the class where your are calling this adapter do like this,

```
ListView hangarList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hangarList);

ListAdapter adapter = new HangarAdapter(this, ship,ship2); // ship2 will be your second string array which you wanna set for second textview.

    hangarList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this will help you! If there are any problems then please feel free to ask.

Comment: I am very glad that I helped you!